# Does there exist a countable partition of [0,1] by disjoint closed subsets?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, gn.general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are the integers with the cofinite topology not path-connected?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970/why-are-the-integers-with-the-cofinite-topology-not-path-connected)

As in the title, is it possible to find closed, disjoint subsets $C_n$ of $[0,1]$ such that $[0,1] = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} C_n$?

Two observations:

1. If we do not demand a *countable* set of subsets, it is sufficient to take every point as a subset.
2. If we consider the particular case where the subsets are closed intervals, then it is not possible. To see that, it is sufficient and not difficult to show that the partition considered is a perfect subset of $\mathbb R$ and so it is not countable. This particular case is even known as Sierpiński's lemma.

Comment: (Presumably you want all the $C_n$ to be nonempty as well.) It's a Baire category argument. A quick google leads back to MO; see this discussion: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970

Comment: And before that, I asked this on MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/is-0-1-a-countable-disjoint-union-of-closed-sets

Comment: The OP references Sierpiński's lemma, but I was not able to find any references to this result. Could someone familiar with this provide a resource?

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially a duplicate of [Why are the integers with the cofinite topology not path-connected?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970) for which I gave an answer that included the following:

Suppose, toward a contradiction, that we had a partition of $[0,1]$ into countably many closed sets $C_n$; I'll write $B_n$ for the boundary of $C_n$ and $B$ for the union of the $B_n$'s.  Observe that, if $p\in B_n$ then each open interval around $p$ meets $B_m$ for some $m\neq n$.  (Proof: As $p$ is in the boundary of $C_n$, the interval contains a point $q$ that is not in $C_n$ and  hence is in some other $C_m$.  If $q\in B_m$ we're done, and otherwise we find a point in $B_m$ between $q$ and $p$.)  This observation means that each $B_n$, considered as a subset of $B$, has empty interior.  But $B$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$ (because its complement is the union of the interiors of the $C_n$'s) and therefore a complete metric space.  By the Baire category theorem, it cannot be covered by countably many closed sets $B_n$ with empty interiors, so we have the desired  contradiction.

Comment: Your answer appeared 1 sec. before my comment. 