# Countable path-connected Hausdorff space

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there a topology $\tau$ on $\omega$ such that $(\omega,\tau)$ is Hausdorff and path-connected?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, a path-connected Hausdorff space is arc-connected, whence it would be of (at least) continuum cardinality provided it has more than one point. This follows from a more general (and deep) result that a Peano space (a compact, connected, locally connected, and metrizable space) is arc-connected if it is path-connected, together with the observation that a Hausdorff space that is the continuous image of the unit interval is a Peano space. See this [section](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+space#arcconnectedness) of the nLab, and references therein.

Comment: Shouldn't you say instead that it has cardinality *at least* continuum? It could be far larger, such as with the cone over an enormous discrete space.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Oh, of course -- I'll edit in. Thanks!

Comment: And I guess we have to add the qualifier, "with at least two points," as well, since the one-point space is a path-connected Hausdorff space, but doesn't have size at least continuum.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Fixed -- thanks again.

Answer (score 30):

Todd has already answered the question, but let me give an
alternative argument.

**Theorem.** Every compact Hausdorff space of size less than the
continuum is totally disconnected.

**Proof.** Suppose $a\neq b$ in a compact Hausdorff space $X$ of
size less than the continuum. Since every compact Hausdorff space is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space),
there is by [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) a
continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)=0$ and
$f(b)=1$. Since $X$ is smaller than the continuum, there is some
real number $z$ strictly between $0$ and $1$ with
$z\notin\text{ran}(f)$. So $\text{ran}(f)$ is disconnected and 
there can be no connected subspace of $X$ containing both
$a$ and $b$. So $X$ is totally disconnected. **QED**

In particular, any such space with at least two points is not
connected.

**Corollary.** There are no nontrivial paths in any Hausdorff
space of size less than the continuum.

**Proof.** The image of a nontrivial path in such a space would be a compact
Hausdorff connected space of size less than the continuum, with at
least two points, contrary to the theorem. **QED**

Comment: Very nice! ${}$

Comment: Right, Joel - Urysohn's function. Thank you Todd for pointing me to Joel's answer. (Frankly, the q. posed above should never be considered "research").

Answer (score 14):

I realise this is quite an old question, but here is an alternative to the already existing elegant answers, which shows that Hausdorff can be replaced by $T_1$:

> **Proposition.** No countable $T_1$ space containing at least two points is the continuous image of an interval.

**Proof.** Suppose $X$ is a $T_1$ topological space (so points are closed), $I:=[0,1]$, and $f\colon I\to X$ is continuous. Then
$$ \{f^{-1}(x)\colon x\in X\}$$
is a partition of $I$ into closed, hence compact, subsets. But $I$ (more generally, any non-trivial continuum) [is not the countable disjoint union of compact proper subsets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48970/why-are-the-integers-with-the-cofinite-topology-not-path-connected). So $X$ is uncountable. $\square$

Observe that the proof, in contrast to Joel's, does not show that the cardinality of $X$ is that of the continuum. On the other hand, there are non-Hausdorff compact $T_1$ spaces, so his proof does not apply to $T_1$ spaces. Likewise for Todd's argument, as there are $T_1$ spaces that are path-connected, but not arcwise connected.

On the other hand, [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) (consisting of two points, only one of which is closed) is both $T_0$ and path-connected. So $T_1$ cannot be replaced by $T_0$.

**EDIT.** It seems this argument is also here: http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Path-connected_and_T1_with_at_least_two_points_implies_uncountable

Comment: Very nice argument, thanks for adding it!