# How big is the smallest nontrivial partition of the unit interval into closed disjoint closed sets?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Consider how we might partition the unit interval in the reals into
disjoint closed sets 
 $$[0,1]=\bigsqcup_i C_i.$$ 
Of course, we could partition the unit interval into singletons, which would make a partition of size
continuum. And it turns out not to be possible to find such a partition with only countably many closed sets.

If the continuum hypothesis fails, perhaps there is a nontrivial partition into fewer than continuum many disjoint closed sets? Yes, indeed, it turns out to be relatively consistent with ZF that this is possible.

So let us define the *closed partition number* $\kappa$, which is
the size of the smallest nontrivial partition of the unit interval
$[0,1]$ in the reals into closed sets.

This number appeared in my answer to a MathOverflow question
concerning the continuum hypothesis and [cofinite topologies being
contractible](https://mathoverflow.net/a/296084/1946), where I
proved that the cofinite topology on a nontrivial set $X$ is
contractible or equivalently path connected if and only if $X$ has
size at least the closed partition number.

In that answer, I had noted that we have some information about the
closed partition number.

- It is uncountable and at most continuum.
  $$\omega_1\leq \kappa\leq \frak{c}$$
- $\text{cov}(\mathcal{M})\leq\kappa$.
- $\frak{d}\leq\kappa$.
- It is relatively consistent that $\kappa=\omega_1<\frak{c}$.

My question is whether we might have more complete information
about this cardinal.

**Question.** How does the closed partition number relate to the
other better-known cardinal characteristics? Is it already known by
another name?

Comment: This seems to be also asked in the following MO Quesion of Taras Banakh: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285780/are-the-sierpi%C5%84ski-cardinal-acute-mathfrak-n-and-its-measure-modification

Comment: Thanks, Ali, I shall close my question as a duplicate of Taras's.